# Force line break for each word

Tags: java, android, android-layout, newline, android-relativelayout

I have "strings" = word representing characters put in array called "bWord" to put the characters in button, the problem is that space " " is considered a character and also put in a button. I wan't the string " " to create a break line instead of calling bWord

words like Book Cover would appear like this :
[B][O][O][K][ ][C][O][V][E][R]

I want it to appear like

[B][O][O][K]

[C][O][V][E][R]

this a picture of the current issue :

[image: here]

I was told to create a new layout, but I don't how to go about this

this is the code I'm using

```
        // draw word buttons

    RelativeLayout wordLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.wordlayout);
    String[] word = ld.getLevelSpecific().getProcessedWord();

    for (int i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
        Button temp = new Button(this);
        temp.setText("");
        temp.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
        temp.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, isd.getWordTextSize());
        temp.setIncludeFontPadding(false);
        temp.setId(idCount * 2 + i); 
        temp.setTag(Integer.valueOf(i));
        temp.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_shape_letter);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams p = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                (int) (isd.getWordButtonSize() * orm.getScaleRatio()-2),
(int) (isd.getWordButtonSize() * orm.getScaleRatio()+6*orm.getScaleRatio()));

        if (i > 0) {
            p.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, idCount * 2 + i - 1);
        } else {
            p.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);
            p.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);
        }


        p.setMargins(isd.getExtraspaceWord()+1, isd.getExtraspaceWord(),
                isd.getExtraspaceWord()+1, isd.getExtraspaceWord());
        temp.setLayoutParams(p);
        bWord[i] = temp;
        temp.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                onWordPressed((Integer) v.getTag());

            }
        });
        wordLayout.addView(temp);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand your question properly.

You mentioned words "Book Cover" but your screenshot shows "Bill Clinton"...

I made a fix to show:

[B][I][L][L]

[C][L][I][N][T][O][N]

Instead of:

[B][I][L][L][ ][C][L][I][N][T][O][N]

**How to fix:**

**Option 1:**

You can replace your RelativeLayout by two LinearLayouts. Line1 and Line2, for example.

Then, during runtime, you call:

```
LinearLayout Line1 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.line1);
LinearLayout Line2 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.line2);
...
if(word[i].equals(" "))
    insertingInFirstLine = false;
...
if(insertingInFirstLine)
    Line1.addView(newButton);
else 
    Line2.addView(newButton);
```

Good point is that you don't need worry about View IDs. Just create to linear layouts with horizontal orientation and put them one below the other.

When the word has one line only, you can set Line2 visibility to "View.GONE"

**Options 2:**

If you really need to use Relative Layout, I updated your "FOR" loop. This way, after a space char (" "), all new views will be added below the first line.
Below is the example:

```
int lineDivider = 1000;
for (int i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
    if(word[i].equalsIgnoreCase(" ")) {
        lineDivider = i;
    } else {
        Button temp = new Button(this);
        ...
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams p = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(                        
                    (int) (isd.getWordButtonSize() * orm.getScaleRatio()-2), 
                    (int) (isd.getWordButtonSize() * orm.getScaleRatio()+6*orm.getScaleRatio()));

        if (i > 0) {
            if(i < lineDivider) {
                // First Line Items
                p.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, idCount * 2 + i - 1);
            } else if (i == lineDivider + 1) {
                // First Item of Second Line
                p.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);
                p.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, idCount * 2);
            } else {
                // Second Line Items
                p.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW,  idCount * 2);
                p.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, idCount * 2 + i - 1);
            }
        } else {
            // First ITEM
            p.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);
            p.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);
        }
        ....
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried using this code, but it shows duplicate local variable "i" error , caused by lineDivider = i; i'm using "i" variable for the letters pool too under the answer section, where u see that facebook button